# How to calculate definite intergrals with respect to positive parts?

Tags: calculus

Now I'm facing with a problem when calculating following definite intergrals:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1(x-u)_{+}(y-u)_{+}du=(x\wedge y)^2(3(x\vee y)-(x\wedge y))/6
\end{eqnarray}
I don't know how to calculate this kind of integral and obtain the right part. Anyone knows? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**Without loss of generality you can suppose that $0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1$.**

Then your integral is:
$$I(x,y)=\int_0^1 (x-u)_+ (y-u)_+ du =\int_0^x (x-u)_+ (y-u)_+ du +\int_x^y (x-u)_+ (y-u)_+ du+\int_y^1 (x-u)_+ (y-u)_+ du$$

- If $u \in (0,x)$ then  $(x-u)_+ (y-u)_+=(x-u)(y_u)$
- If $u \in (x,y)$ then  $(x-u)_+ (y-u)_+=0 \times (y-u)=0$
- If $u \in (y,1)$ then  $(x-u)_+ (y-u)_+=0 \times 0=0$

*Remark: in fact you only have to decompose as $\int_0^1=\int_0^x+\int_x^1$ but in all generality with arbitrary function of $(x-u)_+$ and (y-u)_+ the decomposition $\int_0^1=\int_0^x+\int_x^y+\int_y^1$ is the one to consider*

so:

$$I(x,y)=\int_0^x (x-u)(y-u) du=\frac{1}{6} x^2(x-3y)$$

which is the result you want.

Comment: Thank you so much!